# Converting multi-dimensional array to "single" array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a calendar in PHP and I need to count all the events for each day of the year, in order to display the tiles properly (ex: green for few events, orange for 3-4 events and red for more than 5 events).

Here's the query that I use to get all the days with events, and the number of events in that day:

```
$q1 = $pdo->query("SELECT day, COUNT(*) as number FROM events GROUP BY day");
```

With three events in the DB, and two on the same day, this is the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (2) {
    ["day"]=>
    string(3) "145"
    ["number"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
    ["day"]=>
    string(3) "335"
    ["number"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

When I'm `echo` -ing the days, I keep track of the `$currentDay`  variable, which starts at 1 and will end at 365 once the last day is `echo` 'ed.

I would like to get the value of `number` for each of the days, but I don't know how to do that when the output is a multi-dimensional array like that.

Is there a way to convert that array into something more useful, where I could find the number of events (`number`) by doing something like this:

```
$array[$currentDay]["number"] = $number;
```

If not, what is the best approach to keep the number of SQL queries to the strict minimum? I don't want to end up fetching the events for a day once per day, 365 queries for that is madness. I'm not sure what's the best approach to take in this case.

**EDIT**

To output the days, I start from 1 and go to 12 in a `for` (the months), and for each month, I get the number of days, so it accounts for the leap years with one more day.

The reason I'm using a `day` field in my `events` table is because I tried to keep things simple. There's also a **startTime** and **endTime** field, both Integer's to store the timestamps of the start and end of the event, although I don't know how to count the number of events of the day when using timestamps like that.

Comment: not every year has 365 days

Comment: @Dagon That's true, I edited my post to explain my way of outputting the days a bit better. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I just don't get it, why do you need to convert this multidimensional array into single array? You can access data like this foreach($dataArray as $data){
    echo $data->number;
   }

Comment: Can you post your code of the following: "When I'm echo -ing the days, I keep track of the $currentDay variable, which starts at 1 and will end at 365 once the last day is echo 'ed. "

Comment: Although technically this is a multidimensional array I wouldn't think of it like that.  Its a recordset basically.  The first level of the array is the row number, and the second level is the columns of the row.  You're trying to think of this as a data structure when its a recordset from a database....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is just a simple loop:

```
// Initialize $q1 as you did..
$q1 = ... get stuff from DB

$q2 = array();
foreach ($q1 as $row) {
  $q2[$row['day']] = $row['number'];
}

// At this point, $q2 is the array you want to have.
```

Although, if you want to output just the numbers, you can just write the loop without the extra array.

```
foreach ($q1 as $row) {
  echo "number for ".$row['day']." is ".$row['number']."<br>";
}
```